# regex: confirm if a optional portion was matched

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that can be of two forms, and it is unknown which form it will be each time:

`hello world[0:10];` or `hello world;`

There may or may not be the brackets with numbers. The two words (hello and world) can vary. If the brackets and numbers are there, the first number is always 0 and the second number (10) varies.

I need to capture the first word (hello) and, if it exists, the second number (10). I also need to know which form of the string it was.

`hello world[0:10];` I would capture {hello, 10, form1}, and `hello world;` I would capture {hello, form2}. I don't really care how the "form" is formatted, I just need to be able to differentiate. It can be a bit (1=form1, 0=form2), structural (form1 puts me in one scope and form2 another), etc.

---

I currently have the following *(now working)* regex:

`/(\w*) \s \w* (?:\[0:(\d*)\])?;/x`

This gives me `$1 = hello` and potentially `$2 = 10`. <s>I now just need to know if the bracketed numbers were there or not. This will be repeated many times, so I can't assume `$2 = undef` going into the regex. `$2` could also be the same thing a few times in a row so I can't just look for a change in `$2` before and after the regex.</s>

My best solution so far is to run the regex twice, the first time with the brackets and the second time without:

```
if( /(\w*) \s \w* \[0:(\d*)\];/x ) {...}
elsif( /(\w*) \s \w*;/x ) {...}
```

This seems very inefficient and inelegant though so I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: "visual" of my current regex: https://regex101.com/r/xEW3xj/1/

Comment: I don't understand your issue with not being able to use $2 in your look-ahead example. It will get set each time the regex is applied. Checking for it being defined or not seems like that would give you your form type. Maybe an example with some code would help.

Comment: @UncleCarl you are correct. `$2` will work by checking if defined. I was for some reason thinking `$2` wouldn't get reset if no second set of binding parenthesis existed which in hindsight makes no sense. All the lexical variables get reset on any match so my above code will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `?` to optionally match portions of your regex. Then you can capture the output directly as a return value from the regex.

```
my $re = qr{ (\w*) \s* (?:\[0:(\d+)\])?; }x;
if( my($word, $num) = $line =~ $re ) {
    say "Word: $word";
    say "Num: $num" if defined $num;
}
else {
    say "No match";
}
```

`(?:\[0:(\d+)\])?` says there *may* be a `[0:\d+]`. `(?:)` makes the grouping non-capturing so only `\d+` is captured.

`$1` and `$2` are also safe to use, they are reset on each match, but using lexical variables makes things more explicit.

Comment: You are correct about adding the ? to the regex. When I copied and pasted the regex from one place to another I forgot to add it back in. I fixed my question now.

Comment: `$2` being reset each match makes it work. You are correct. I for some reason thought `$2` wouldn't get reset on the chance there is no second capture parenthesis to match. Which in hindsight makes no sense.

Comment: There seem to be *two* words before the brackets. The OP wants the first of them, so the pattern should be something like `/(\w*) \s* \w+ (?:\[0:(\d+)\])?; /x`